# $scope variable access in ng-option filter angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

how to access $scope variable in filter option please help me.

```
       $scope.Profile = Auth.getCurrentUserSync();
```

HTML

```
 <select class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer" ng-model="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer" ng-options="customer.full_name for customer in postjobcustomerCtrl.atlasCustomers  | filter:{full_name:"+Profile.full_name+"} track by customer.user_id"
                                            ng-change="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectDefaultAddress()" required></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `$scope` variable without any interpolation:

```
filter:{full_name: Profile.full_name }
```

Comment: when i enter filter:{full_name:'Rischard'} ITS worKING FINE, but your answer show me all customer list,